# Match multiple element names of a specific parent element

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am used to matching multiple elements like this:

```
<xsl:template match="horse | sheep | pig | cow | dog">
```

But how can I restrict this to such elements which are children of a given parent type.
e.g. it would match:

```
<animals>
 <horse .../>
 <sheep .../>
</animals>
```

But not match:

```
<pets>
 <horse .../>
 <dog .../>
</pets>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to spell that out as `<xsl:template match="animals/horse | animals/sheep | animals/pig | animals/cow | animals/dog">`.